# Can't change font in wicked pdf

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

The document prints just fine, but I cant seem to change the font no matter what I do!? The code starts with these stylesheets.

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'proficiency_card' %>
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag 'pdf' %>
```

the 'pdf' stylesheet looks like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@include make-grid(sm);
@include make-grid(md);
@include make-grid(lg);
```

and the 'proficiency_card' stylesheet is regular css, like this:

```
.proficiency-card {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
}

.info-field {
    border: 1px solid #3E7B8E;
    padding: 0.5em;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

etc.

If I alter the font-size values or color values, I get the appropriate change in the document, but when I change the `font-family` I get nothing. I'm not trying to use any custom font, I'm trying to get a basic one, like `font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, Serif`.

The font doesn't seem to be defined anywhere else, so I'm assuming its coming from the bootsrap/variables or mixins!? If so, is there a way to overwrite the default font settings that I'm missing?

Comment: I am not in front of my computer to check, but I remember having reviewed my CSS files recently and all Wicked pdf css files included fonts as Base 64 encoded. You dig this option.